# Is there a way to prevent toggling of input text when hiding an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to hide a `div` when typing into an input field. The functionality I am looking for is to hide the div when typing and to unhide it if all input is backspaced.

My problem is when I type one letter it hides but on the next key press it shows. I am struggling to find an event handler that doesn't toggle the "TEST" `div` (I have tried a few of [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup)). Can I do it with an event handler or do I need to work on a more specific function?

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-butterfly-0twdn)

JS:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(true);
  const hide = () => setIsTyping(!isTyping);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname" onKeyPress={hide} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className={isTyping ? "block" : "hide"}> TEST </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I am new to react and am still working out the kinks.

Comment: so you want the div to be visible only when input value length is 0?

Comment: @DanCantir Basically yeah, when the user starts typing hide and show when zero or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const storeValue = (e) => setValue(e.target.value || '');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      First name: <input type="text" value={value} name="fname" onChange={storeValue} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className={value.length === 0 ? "block" : "hide"}> TEST </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the updated link: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mendel-bo9i1?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work, but hopefully this might give you an idea! (NOT REACT GUY) https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-knuth-7hs4z